What is the focus of the tag Software? Remove it?
It is not clear to me what the focus of software is supposed to be. Most software used with Bitcoin can either be specified more distinctly, as "wallet", "client", "miner", "website", "exchange", or one of the many tags that refer to specific programs.
software currently has the tag description "Computer programs relevant to Bitcoin or similar technologies". I think it may classify as a meta-tag.
Either the use-case of software should be clarified, or it should be removed altogether.

I'd agree, it's better to just mention the specific software that you're dealing with, this is a meta tag. It probably grows because folks sometimes can't create software specific tags if they're new, and it's there. 
Thankfully, it's only on about 60 questions, but these need to be examined to make sure that we don't need to create a software specific tag, and then it can be burninated and blacklisted to the outer realms.
Once you're sure it's safe to burn, ping me and I'll look at getting it done.

Shouldn't the tag disappear by itself, when it isn't used on any questions anymore?
